# Simple select statement of SQLite takes more than 2 seconds

Tags: java, android

I have indexed the table "CREATE INDEX Items_idx ON Items(Itemcode,Barcode);"
and inserted more than 400 thousand of lines there . How to increase speed in select and return data faster ?

```
  public static Item instanceFromDBBarcode(SQLiteDatabase db, String  itemBarcode) {

    String[] args = {itemBarcode};
    String sql  ="SELECT * FROM Items WHERE "+BARCODE+"=?;
    Cursor reader = db.rawQuery(sql, args);
    if (reader.moveToNext()) {
        Item i = readCurrentItem(reader);
        reader.close();
        return i;
    }
    reader.close();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Show an example of a full query (`BARCODE`).

Comment: SELECT * FROM Items WHERE "+BARCODE+" = '5606428138681'

Comment: I suppose BARCODE gets replaced with a column name? Also, BARCODE looks like a constant, but it still looks like this is exposing you to potential SqlInjection

Comment: Sorry I mean thousands not hundred ,400k ! :\

Comment: Index is backwards CREATE INDEX Items_idx ON Items(barcode,Itemcode);

Answer (score 0):

For 400 records your issue will not be whether a column is indexed. A sequential scan of 400 records will be trivial for a modern database.
I believe your index is not doing what you anticipate it to, however. An index on (itemcode, barcode) will not help with queries only querying barcode, you should create an index on just barcode.

Comment: Sorry I mean thousands not hundred ,400k ! :\

Comment: @TestLogical 400k rows in SQLite database? This is not what SQLite is for. Anyway you'll have to wait.